# array of weeks in momentjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods, momentjs

I need to get an array of weeks that each contain 7 days using moment(), but pushing an object to array replaces the whole array it seems.

```
const start = moment().clone().startOf('month').startOf('week');
const end = start.clone().add(6, 'week').subtract(1, 'day');

const weeks = [];
let days = [];

for (let day = start; day.isSameOrBefore(end); day.add(1, 'day')) {
    days.push({
        date: day.date()
    });

    if (day.clone().endOf('isoWeek')) {
        weeks.push(days);
        days = [];
    }
}

console.log(weeks);
```

weeks.length should be 6 but it's 42.

Example codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZbKBR?editors=1111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was `moment().endOf('isoWeek')` mutates the moment to the end of the week instead of returning boolean so `day.clone().endOf('isoWeek').diff(day, 'days') === 0` works